# Wi-Fi constantly disconnects

Tags: kernel, debian, wifi

Using either NetworkManager or Wicd to manage wireless networking on my Wi-Fi-powered laptop, too often I get randomly disconnected, and I see these messages on **/var/log/syslog**:

```
Dec 10 05:21:26 debian dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 10.0.0.2 port 67
Dec 10 05:21:26 debian dhclient: DHCPACK from 10.0.0.2
Dec 10 05:21:26 debian dhclient: bound to 10.0.0.4 -- renewal in 1662 seconds.
Dec 10 05:40:38 debian kernel: [105982.935232] iwlagn 0000:06:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
Dec 10 05:40:38 debian kernel: [105983.182330] Registered led device: iwl-phy0::radio
Dec 10 05:40:38 debian kernel: [105983.182586] Registered led device: iwl-phy0::assoc
Dec 10 05:40:38 debian kernel: [105983.182658] Registered led device: iwl-phy0::RX
Dec 10 05:40:38 debian kernel: [105983.182872] Registered led device: iwl-phy0::TX
```

*I think **05:40:38** is the first line that indicates trouble*

With NetworkManager, I recover from this situation with the following command each time this happens:

```
nmcli nm wifi off && nmcli nm wifi on
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem #1 SMP Thu Nov 25 19:30:54 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**notes**:

- Wi-Fi chipset is Intel's **4965**.
- I reproduced this problem on **2.6.32**, **2.6.36** and **2.6.37-rc4** kernel versions.

Comment: It looks for me like kernel error (i.e. it returns errno -34) or networkmanager (i.e. it checks errno variable when it shouldn't).

Comment: @Mac I updated the log lines. I think I selected wrong ones last time.

Comment: Ok. Now it looks like hardware/firmware(microcode)/kernel error. Probably either hardware or firmware. The NM does not notice the restart - hence the error.

Comment: __note__: I haven't experienced this problem for weeks now, and have no idea what 'fixed' it. Nothing points to the kernel either.

Comment: **note**: Well, I'm experiencing it again, but less randomly. I'm back using **2.6.32**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with the iwlagn driver.  Updating the driver and/or firmware may fix your issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/200509